# how to force maven to update local repo

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I compiled a jar file in one project so it can be consumed in the 2nd one. I can see the jar file in .m2 folder. But in the 2nd project it complains about artifact not found. 
I guess I have to force maven to update indices/cache something but don't know what exactly. Any tip, thanks.

Update: thanks for all good suggestions. 
Turns out that the maven plugin (of IntelliJ) in the second project doesn't update its index. I use command line it compiled ok.

Comment: This question needs more detail.  Can you show the relevant part of your poms of both your projects, explain how you 'compiled a jar file', how you got it into the .m2 dir?  Did you use `mvn install`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are installing into local repository, there is no special index/cache update needed.

Make sure that:

1. You have installed the first artifact in your local repository properly. Simply copying the file to `.m2` may not work as expected.  Make sure you install it by `mvn install`
2. The dependency in 2nd project is setup correctly.  Check on any typo in `groupId/artifactId/version`, or unmatched artifact `type/classifier`.

Answer (score 54):

try using `-U` (*aka* `--update-snapshots`) when you run maven

And make sure the dependency definition is correct

Comment: -U is only for updating snapshots from remote repo.  Given that OP is talking about compiling the JAR himself, and haven't mentioned about snapshot, I doubt if this answer is reasonable.

Comment: Well, OK, half the answer is unreasonable.  The other half is identical to half of yours :)  Which is more likely the case

Answer (score 20):

You can also use this command on the command line:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean install
```

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html

Answer (score 6):

Even though this is an old question, I 've stumbled upon this issue multiple times and until now never figured out how to fix it. The *update maven indices* is a term coined by IntelliJ, and if it still doesn't work after you've compiled the first project, chances are that you are using 2 different maven installations.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to open up the Actions menu. Type `Maven` and go to *Maven Settings*. Check the *Home Directory* to use the same maven as you use via the command line

Comment: Click on `Reimport All Maven Projects` to force IntelliJ to download all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Click settings and search for "Repositories", then select the local repo and click "Update". That's all. This action meets my need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are struggling with authenticating to a site, and Maven is caching the results, simply removing the meta-data about the site from the meta-data stash will force Maven to revisit the site.

```
gvim <local-git-repository>/commons-codec/resolver-status.properties
```