# Nexus / Maven - The POM for ... is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, nexus

I'm facing a bunch of warnings like "The POM for ... is missing, no dependency information available" while building my maven java project.

The artifacts are stored in the Nexus server hosted in our company. The problem started after I scheduled a task in Nexus to "Remove Releases From Repository" in order to clean up it and maintain only the 2 last releases.

Because of that, I'm receiving these warnings for the old-removed releases:

```
[WARNING] The POM for xpto:jar:jar:8.16.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for xpto:jar:jar:8.17.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for xpto:jar:jar:8.18.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for xpto:jar:jar:8.19.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

Once I have many component projects and the releases are constants, when a compile some project that use these components, I get a lot of warnings like that.

Do you guys propose some way to avoid these warning or execute some goal at client side that could re-resolve or reindex the dependencies?

Regards,

Comment: Releases should never being removed cause releases are immutable. If you have removed them you could check if they are in nexus Trash otherwise you should have a good backup. If those artifacts are from other repositories like Maven Central you could open the access to Central and just rebuild those projects which need them so they could be downloaded again.

Comment: In my case I don't need to keep the older versions and support rollback. Take a look: https://support.sonatype.com/entries/20871791-Can-I-delete-releases-from-Nexus-after-they-have-been-published-
The Nexus side is ok. But the maven client side is showing me the warnings.

Comment: You don't have them in your nexus and it shows that you need them which in consequence means you should not delete them. Solution: Rebuild the projects which use them if they are from other repositories. The warning means you need them but you don't have them in your repository.

Comment: I don't have in other repository once these artifacts aren't public... Any other option?

Comment: I also tried removing the local repository and nothing changed...

Comment: So in result i have to say you really have to check your backup which i hope you have, otherwise you are in trouble. The warnings shows that you need those artifacts which means also the given linke to the sonatype page does not fit for you. The question is: Is wasting some amount of hard drive space(which is not really the case here) worth the problems you have now? I don't think so.

Comment: If these are presumable internal project couldn't you recreate those artifacts from the sources and deploy them into Nexus again? I hope your sources with all release is in your version control?

Comment: I've source control and conditions to rebuild it. The trash are empty. The problem is the number of components, releases and the needless of rollback to old versions. I thank you a lot @khmarbaise for helping me but I can't agree with that. Why Sonatype posted some article like this http://goo.gl/YuDUQW and why does Nexus has the task "Remove Releases From Repository". I can't believe anyone needed it. Do you know how maven resolve the dependencies, once the local repo is empty and Nexus doesn't have the releases and the index was rebuilt?

Comment: The problem you are describing in the question is a contradiction in itself related to the things your are saying...You need those releases. That's the point. The dependencies will be requested from nexus. If Nexus does not have them Nexus will try to resolve them from other repository which are configured in Nexus. Apart from that the needles of rollback of old versions you describe is exactly the oposite of what you are asking for. So either you have a good backup or you can rebuild them you are lost...That's unfortunately the hard truth.

Comment: Let me make a statement: the libraries I'm receiving warning aren't a dependency in my pom. I'm referencing the latest version (e.g. version -> [8.0.0,),[LATEST])

Comment: I would suggest to remove version ranges in general. Define the version you need and that's it.

Comment: I didn't need to remove version ranges. After more research I could get to the point I needed for my business. Thank you @khmarbaise for your comments. Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sometimes Releases are Disposable](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/20871791-Can-I-delete-releases-from-Nexus-after-they-have-been-published-)

As the article above describes, depending on your business, you may not need to store old releases on your own repository. I'm included in this scenario.

In order to maintain, for example, only the 2 last releases from my component projects, some steps should be followed in order to avoid the maven [WARNING] messages:

### 1. Remove releases from repository

You should add a task to your repository to maintain the only **n** release itens. This can be done by:

- Go to Sonatype Nexus > Administration > Scheduled Tasks > Add
- Set "Task Type" to "Remove Releases From Repository"
- Setup your own parameters (e-mail, recurrence, etc.)

### 2. Rebuild maven metadata files

The "ace in the hole" for this question is to rebuild the maven metadata files (maven-metadata.xml), once they were going to maintain the old releases information until the time they are going to be rebuild. This can be done by:

- Go to Sonatype Nexus > Administration > Scheduled Tasks > Add
- **Set "Task Type" to "Rebuild Maven Metadata Files"**
- Setup your own parameters (e-mail, recurrence, etc.)
- Attention: this task must run after the "Remove Releases From Repository"

### 3. Local repository

Now, the local repository need to know that metadata files were updated. This can be done by the parameter:

- mvn -U:

  -U,--update-snapshots                  Forces a check for updated
                                          releases and snapshots on remote
- For example:

  mvn -U clean package

### References

- [Can I delete releases from Nexus after they have been published?](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/20871791-Can-I-delete-releases-from-Nexus-after-they-have-been-published-)
- [What do the scheduled tasks in Nexus do, and how often should I run them?](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/26829788-What-do-the-scheduled-tasks-in-Nexus-do-and-how-often-should-I-run-them-)
- [How to force maven to update local repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673431/how-to-force-maven-to-update-local-repo)

Answer (score 3):

Check your `settings.xml`, i.e. exported as such in bash:

```
export MVN_SETTINGS=~/.m2/settings.xml
```

This warning typically appears when you can't download the dependencies from the internet.