# Maven: "Could not find artifact package:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT"?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I've tried installing a Spring project, and had one created from start.spring.io. However, when trying to run `mvn clean install`, I have run into errors:

**`Could not find artifact com.sof:game-mix:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT`**

I know this is has happened to others, and I've checked [these threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349129/nexus-maven-the-pom-for-is-missing-no-dependency-information-available) [for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349129/nexus-maven-the-pom-for-is-missing-no-dependency-information-available) but unfortunately my attempts to replicate their solutions haven't worked for me.

[Here is a link to my project](https://mega.nz/#!pLoGBKJJ!2LHxUOEW-VJpKgaz2Hzy_xwNo-DrKl2sPOH0-sqsOdE), for anyone who wishes to replicate the project and see if mvn clean install might work for them. Otherwise, the code for my pom.xml files is below

I have three pom.xml files:

Root pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sof</groupId>
    <artifactId>game-mix</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <java.version>13</java.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

My web module's pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>game-mix</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.sof</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>web</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <!--dependency for our core module-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sof</groupId>
            <artifactId>game-mix</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--dependency for spring boot-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Thymeleaf Dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring Boot devtools-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my core module's pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>game-mix</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.sof</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>core</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Where exactly am I going wrong? I'd appreciate any assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted my first answer because I did not read your POMs thoroughly enough.

`com.sof:game-mix:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT` is your parent POM. You cannot reference it as a `<dependency>`.

Comment: I see. So should I remove the references to it in my modules' POM dependencies?

Comment: Yes. Dependencies should be jars that you use in your source code. Parent POMs are only put into the `<parent>` tag.